# How to setup virtual machines on cloud for testing environment

Tags: testing, selenium, automated-tests, admin, development-environment

I have to setup Test environment to run my Selenium scripts on different Operating systems and  Browsers.

Can any one assist me what is the best solution for this ?
We have to test as per below matrix.

Win7 IE7, IE8, IE9 , Safari
XP: IE7,IE8
Mac Safari
VIsta : IE7, IE8

Here is how I set my driver:

```
if (browser1.equalsIgnoreCase("chrome")) {
  File file = new File(CONFIG.getProperty("CHROME_DRIVER_EXE"));
  System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", file.getAbsolutePath());
  driver = new ChromeDriver();
  builder = new Actions(driver); 
  bckdbrowser = new WebDriverBackedSelenium(driver, ConfigReader.ENVIRONMENT_URL);
  driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
}
```

Comment: I need more info.  What testing framework do you use, and how do you create your drivers currently?

Comment: I have created two type of frameworks which runs single browser each time In my framework I am giving Browser names and OS details in Config.Properties file. Other one is Selenium Grid which runs multiple Browsers parallely. But every thing is in my laptop.. I have setup some testing environment to run for Different OS and Browsers.

Comment: If you wrote the frameworks yourself, then I need to see the code.  If you are using something like TestNG or JUnit, then I need to see it there.  My second question still stands...in your code, how do you create your driver instances (I actually want to see the code)?

Comment: if (browser1.equalsIgnoreCase("chrome")) {
   File file = new File(CONFIG.getProperty("CHROME_DRIVER_EXE"));
   System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", file.getAbsolutePath());
   driver = new ChromeDriver();
   builder = new Actions(driver); 
   bckdbrowser = new WebDriverBackedSelenium(driver,
     ConfigReader.ENVIRONMENT_URL);
   driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10,TimeUnit.SECONDS );

Comment: And I am using Testng

Answer (score 0):

Ok.  There are different ways to do what you want, using TestNG.  I am going to provide a brief overview of each, as there is lots of documentation on how to do them.

The first is to use @Factory, and instantiate a new class for each driver.

The second is to use @Dataprovider and pass in a driver to your methods.  This has the flexibility of being parallel.

With the actual task of instantiating each of your drivers...there are plenty of resources on doing that.